# how to direct open Gmail mail composer in android?

Tags: android, gmail

I am using the following code. Problem it that when I run this code on device. It open a Dailogbox that hase 3 options for sending a mail. "POP , email , gmail" etc. 
By clicking the gamil the composer appear. 
  **I just want to show Gamil mail composer directly.** Instead of showing a dailog box for choosing the options. Please help me.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");

String subject = "My Subject";

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

emailIntent.setType("text/html");

String title = "<p align='center'>" + storyTitle + "<br/>" + storyPubDate + "</p>";

String data = "<p> Sent From ABC APP Sent from my Android </p>";

            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(title + data));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

Answer (score 26):

Try this one, Perfect

```
public void shareToGMail(String[] email, String subject, String content) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, email);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
    final PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0);
    ResolveInfo best = null;
    for(final ResolveInfo info : matches)
        if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm") || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("gmail"))
            best = info;
    if (best != null)
        emailIntent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName, best.activityInfo.name);
    activity.startActivity(emailIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Not sure about the need for the chooser. This is from one of my apps...

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"jimblackler@gmail.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Note that setType should be text/plain not plain/text (otherwise you get an ActivityNotFoundException). Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

Try this code

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
 "mailto", "abc@gmail.com", null));
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "This is my subject text");
 context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, null));
```

Ref:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO\

Answer (score 2):

Below code worked for me. This will search for an email client and directly launch the new email composer with the sent values pre-populated. If no email client exists then then that should be caught to avoid crash.

The good think about this solution is that, on back press it takes you directly to your app screen where the email intent was started from.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your Subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The message");
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Mail account not configured", Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't bypass this popup programatically. What will happen if a user tries to access the functionality and doesn't have GMail configured?

If you want to bypass is just remove all other email clients so that GMail is the only one that can send/recieve emails. That way the popup will not appear.

Comment: yes, There must be not, if Gmail is not configured. But how can I remove all other client from my device?

Answer (score 0):

If you have several mail composer in your android device and you just want Gamil composer start for your request, you have to

```
emailIntent.setClassName("xxxgamil composer package name xxx", "xxxgmail composer class name xxx");  
    startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: I found the code. It look like your code 
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,0);
    ResolveInfo best=null;
    for (final ResolveInfo info : matches)
      if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm") ||
          info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("gmail")) best=info;
    if (best!=null)
      intent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName, best.activityInfo.name);
    startActivity(intent);

Comment: Done. But after sending the mail. It again show to dialog box. I don't want to open it any more?
Any suggestion?

Comment: if you already specified the class name, you should got the composer activity directly, doesn't it?