# How to avoid Dialog box after sending mail from Gmail in Android?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-intent

I am just use the code [how to direct open Gmail mail composer in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789545/how-to-direct-open-gmail-mail-composer-in-android)
Problem is that after sending the mail. A dialog box is open that show options of "Mail, Gmail, Bluetooth"
I just want to avoid it. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I send e-mails with the following method.  When it's called it opens a dialog that allows the user to edit the body and hit send.  After sending the dialog is gone.

```
private void SendErrorMail( Context _context, String ErrorContent )
{
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    String subject = _context.getResources().getString( R.string.CrashReport_MailSubject );
    String body = _context.getResources().getString( R.string.CrashReport_MailBody ) +
    "\n\n"+
    ErrorContent+
    "\n\n";
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, getEmailAddressees());
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    _context.startActivity( Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Title:") );
}
```