# ACTION_SEND force sending with email

Tags: android, email, android-intent

every time i create an action for sending an email from my app, it prompts to many options including a QR client...

Is there a way to force sending via email clients only?

**Code for sending the email**

```
String rec[] = { owner.email };
i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, rec);
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "RE: " + desc);
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
        "\n\n\nSent from Mojo for Android");
startActivity(i);
```

**Screenshot for what happens when I launch this**
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5802670/599993

Comment: Use Intent.ACTION_SENDTO with "mailto:" schema. Check this answer for better details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42856167/3257025

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try to setType `message/rfc822` instead of `text/plain`

Comment: Is there a way to narrow it down to force it to send with Gmail?

Comment: if i have to use setType for my attachment(file) type? +1 if i need to send only text

Comment: what about `text/html` ?

Answer (score 5):

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
new String[] { "abc@xyz.com" });
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    "Subject of the Mail");
emailIntent.putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                           "This is my sample Mail");
emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

else use this it will shows only the mail clients,

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
new String[] { "abc@xyz.com" });
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    "Subject of the Mail");
emailIntent.putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                           "This is my sample Mail");
//emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should change the `setType` to

```
i.setType("message/rfc822") ;
```

Comment: Yes, this defaulted to opening Gmail in my app.  Thanks!

Comment: it opens a lot more apps, than just email..., why not `text/html` ?

Answer (score 4):

Even though it's too late for @thepoosh, but it may be helpful for future questioners. After a lot of searching and testing, I finally found a good solution.
Thanks to the Open source developer, [**cketti**](https://gist.github.com/cketti) for sharing his/her concise solution.

```
String mailto = "mailto:bob@example.org" +
    "?cc=" + "alice@example.com" +
    "&subject=" + Uri.encode(subject) +
    "&body=" + Uri.encode(bodyText);

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse(mailto));

try {
  startActivity(emailIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
  //TODO: Handle case where no email app is available
}
```

[This](https://gist.github.com/cketti/6a9b67dd92540bc74b2e#file-emailintent-java) is the link to his/her gist.

Answer (score 1):

It will show all the available app installed on android phone which can perform sharing or send a link from webview to others. Like - Gmail, facebook, imo, whatsapp, messenger etc.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
String shareLink = webView.getUrl();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareLink);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via..."));
```

But when you force to open mail app only :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"something@gmail.com"});

try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "send mail"));
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No mail app found!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Unexpected Error!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using `ACTION_SEND` with type `text/plain`, it will show all the valid options. However, if you want, you may design your your own dialog window which shows only Gmail or other mail client by doing filtering programatically.

BTW, why do you even need this window when you just want to use Gmail?

Comment: if I recall correctly you can't force Gmail as a default email client

Comment: nop, i'm asking you to show Gmail in your own custom designed dialog window

Comment: I wouldn't want to force my users to use a specific emailing client. it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:?to=email&subject=hello&body=hello%20world"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send via..."));
```

you can try this:::::

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent.setType("plain/text");
```

At first when I spotted this I immediately though it was a mistake and it was meant to be `text/plain`, but this is actually the correct way to only display E-mail clients in the application list.

Give it a try and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`intent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");` //Added Gmail Package to forcefully open Gmail App

Answer (score -1):

```
String rec[] = { owner.email };
i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822") ;
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, rec);
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "RE: " + desc);
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
        "\n\n\nSent from Mojo for Android");
startActivity(i);
```

try this;:::